# extract words in string with unicode characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, unicode

In javascript (`nodejs`) I need to index text strings with unicode characters, i.e given a string like:

```
"Bonjour à tous le monde, 
je voulais être le premier à vous dire:
  -'comment ça va'
  -<est-ce qu'il fait beau?>"
```

I want to get the following array of words :

```
 ["Bonjour", "à", "tous", "le", "monde", "je", "voulais", "être", ... "beau"]
```

How can I achieve that using regex or any other means ?

ps: I installed and tried the xregexp module which provides unicode support for javascript, but being utterly useless with regexes in general, I could not go very far ...

Comment: A regex like `[^\s]*` should be enough I think.

Comment: Define “word” and specify which language(s) are to be processed. The rules for word boundaries are heavily language-dependent, and the concept of word is vague. Is “est-ce” two words or one? If “qu’il” is two words (as it logically is), what is the first word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the version of [XRegExp bundled with addons](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) which (amongst others) adds  support for regex unicode categories. We are interested in the category `not an unicode letter` that is `\P{L}`.
You can then split your string by the regex `XRegExp("\\P{L}+")`.

```
var s="Bonjour à tous le monde,\nje voulais être le premier à vous dire:\n  -'comment ça va'\n  -<est-ce qu'il fait beau?>";
var notALetter = XRegExp("\\P{L}+");
var words = XRegExp.split(s, notALetter);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWMPT/1/).

Comment: I have to add that using XRegExp solves the issue, but as far as I can see, performance is HORRIBLE and I mean HORRIBLE to the point of making it useless: XRegExp.split(s, notALetter) can take several hundred ms even for a string containing less then 100 characters. So anyone having the same problem should be aware of that. The docs say XRegExp compiles to native RegexEx so there should not be any performance hit, but that's not what I'm seeing - maybe that's because of the unicode plugin ?

Comment: recent version of xregexp is much faster, at least 40x faster than uwords. matching words with `XRegExp.match(content, XRegExp('\\p{L}+', 'g'))` is faster than splitting on non-words

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use the library "uwords" - https://github.com/AlexAtNet/uwords. It extracts words from the text by grouping together characters from L* Unicode groups.

It works similar to `XRegExp("\\p{L}+")` but it is extremely fast.

Example:

```
var uwords = require('uwords');
var words = uwords('Bonjour à tous le monde,\n' +
    'je voulais être le premier à vous dire:\n' +
    '-\'comment ça va\'\n' +
    '-<est-ce qu\'il fait beau?>');
console.log(words);

[ 'Bonjour',
  'à',
  'tous',
  'le',
  'monde',
  'je',
  'voulais',
  'être',
  'le',
  'premier',
  'à',
  'vous',
  'dire',
  'comment',
  'ça',
  'va',
  'est',
  'ce',
  'qu',
  'il',
  'fait',
  'beau' ]
```

P.S. Sorry for being late - I hope it is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

An idea could be to split the string by the various characters that are NOT part of words and then filter out empty strings:

```
var str = "Bonjour à tous le monde, je voulais être le premier à vous dire:  -'comment ça va'  -<est-ce qu'il fait beau?>";

var result = str.split(/[-:'"?\s><]+/).filter(function(item) { return item !== '' });
/*
["Bonjour", "à", "tous", "le", "monde,", "je", "voulais", "être", "le", "premier", "à", "vous", "ire", "comment", "ça", "va", "est", "ce", "qu", "il", "fait", "beau"]
*/
```

Similarly you could match by the negated character class above and you don't have to filter empty strings:

```
var result = str.match(/[^-:'"?\s><]+/g);
```